# Can I save Binh?

Tags: wasteland-2

In Damonta, is it possible to save Binh and return her to her parents?

I received no dialog challenges (Smart Ass, Kiss Ass, etc.) during the conversations with Tinker to prevent her from stopping Binh's heart.

Is there any possible outcome that would save Binh's life?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a specific sequence to this that I don't think anyone has explicitly mentioned.

Upon entering the room with the Tinker, in one corner of the room (across from the prison cell) are a set of three computers.

- One computer is larger than the others.  You must use Computer Science on this first.
- Then you need to check the other smaller two (right click to look at the terminals).  One will be a "capacitive overload" and the other will disable the "wi-fi."  Use Computer Science on the wi-fi computer.

The larger computer can be destroyed by shooting it, but this kills Binh.  Hacking the other computer also kills Binh.  When Binh dies, you'll get a "Log Book Updated" notification.  Doing the "wrong thing" makes the fight easier by damaging the robots and/or applying negative status effects to them.

I was also careful not to shoot towards the larger computer, lest I damage it by mistake.

Tinker will also explode when destroyed, so I made sure she(?) was away from both Binh and the larger computer prior to killing her.  (I don't know if this mattered, but it seemed worth it anyhow)

I did the hacking before combat initiated.  The "wifi" hack caused Tinker to notice me immediately, so set your team up for combat before doing this hack.  You can also do the hacking while combat is going, it takes 4 AP per attempt.

Tinker will also pause when you get her down to critical health, although talking to her made her blow up in my face, so on my final run through I just shot her rather than attempt to initiate conversation.

Comment: I've killed Tinker while he was next to Binh, and she survived fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

As far as I can recall there're 3 computers in the corner of the warehouse where you can find Binh, and you have to hack all of them (**in right order!**) to prevent Tinker to kill Binh remotely. You can hack one before the fight, and after Tinker drops down to certain health, she will stop fighting, then you can hack the others. Repeat 2-3 times (hack->fight) till you done the hacking job and you're good to go.

Comment: I found hacking to be quite unreliable, I had to reload several times since Tinker reacted to the hacking by killing Binh.

Comment: You have to hack the computers in right order. And I can't remember it... I check the description of the computer to figure out which to go first

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

I went into the room, setup my team by the entrance, sent my tech up the LEFT wall (by the door), turn left at the first left, there are 3(?) computers there that can be hacked, iirc I hacked 1 or 2 of them before being noticed, but this turned off his "network".

Once noticed fight started I killed everything, and Binh was on the table alive with a robot heart, also guy in cage was normal. (for him) (though maybe he always is)

To be honest I'm not sure if it was the hacking that saved her, or the fact that I never talked to the tinker and only fought.

Comment: Yeah, if you hack the terminals and disable the Wifi then Tinker is unable to detonate Binh by remote, so they will keep fighting you.

You can still hack them during combat.

Answer (score 0):

When the battle starts just shoot the big computer (its description already hints that it can be destroyed easily).

Answer (score -1):

When you disarm the remote Wi-fi terminal first it will initiate fight. If you disable the biggest one, and by damaging the Tinker 50% to halt the fight and disable the wi-fi she will just kill Bihn. The only way to save Bihn is simple skip dialog and disable the big one and the Wi-Fi console which will start battle and kill Tinker or dmg tinker enough it will try to speak with you and make you come close and blow up.